# Visual Studio debugging .net core app on ubuntu via ssh

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04

I would like to debug .NetCore application which is running on remote Ubuntu server. Workstation from which application is debugged runs on Windows 10 and I would like to debug application in Visual studio 2019 using ssh tunel.

I can successfully connect using ssh as you can see in attached screenshot
[Visual Studio - Attach process window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4lX7.png)

I can see my process running and when I choose it I get operation canceled exception
[Operation was canceled error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUswa.png)

There is no clue why this error occured even in visual studio output window
[Visual studio output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BBNh.png)

I tried to install this versions of VS:
16.10.4
16.9.9
16.8.7

.Net app is running on:
Ubuntu 18.04.5 .Net 3.1.404

Comment: is this process running in debug or in production?

Comment: dlls are built using debug configuration if this is what you mean